# Can I force a WiFi connection retry after x minutes?

Tags: wi-fi

The Wifi SSID in my home is the default SSID of the used router. (I have no means to change it, unfortunately). The problem is, if I travel around my city, my Android phone inevitably finds a network with the same SSID but the password doesn't match. Since then, the network is stuck in "Authentification failed" until I manually force a reconnect.

Is there a way to force my phone to retry connection attempts to known networks e.g. every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous applications on Google Play Store. I had a similar problem a couple of months ago. I used an application named WiFi reconnect as I recall.

- [WiFi Automatic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wifiAutoOff&hl=en)
- [WiFi Reconnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.programminglife.wifireconnect&hl=en)